# Parsing string to json on android

Tags: android, json

How to parse HTTP response ton JSON object ?

I changed my json code to:

```
{
    "data": [{
        "id": 1,
        "sensor1": 76,
        "sensor2": 75
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "sensor1": 76,
        "sensor2": 206
    }]
}
```

And my code is now:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(mJson);
try {
data = json.getJSONArray("data");
for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) data.get(i);

    map.put(TAG_SENSOR_1, obj.getInt("sensor1"));
    map.put(TAG_SENSOR_2, obj.getInt("sensor2"));

    dataList.add(data.getInt("id") - 1, map);
}
} catch (JSONException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But I have the same problem

Comment: What library are you using to parse the JSON? The value that you're passing to it is not valid JSON data, hence the error.

Comment: It would appear that this array of arrays is stored as a string. It is likely enclosed by quotes in the raw json data.

Comment: What code you are trying to parse this JSON?

Comment: your string is not in Json format

Comment: I use: JSONObject json = new JSONObject(my_json_string);

Comment: My code: 
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
  try {
      data = json.getJSONArray("data");
      for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
   // creating new HashMap
   HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
   JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) data.get(i);
   
   map.put(TAG_SENSOR_1, obj.getInt("sensor1"));
   map.put(TAG_SENSOR_2, obj.getInt("sensor2"));
   dataList.add(data.getInt(0) - 1, map);
      }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

Comment: Post your error console

Comment: 01-08 06:57:12.533: E/Buffer Error(2787): Error converting result org.json.JSONException: Value {"data": [{"sensor4": 73, "sensor1": 76, "sensor3": 73, "sensor2": 75, "sensor5": 73, "id": 1}, {"sensor4": 73, "sensor1": 76, "sensor3": 73, "sensor2": 206, "sensor5": 73, "id": 2}, {"sensor4": 73, "sensor1": 76, "sensor3": 73, "sensor2": 75, "sensor5": 73, "id": 3}, {"sensor4": 73, "sensor1": 76, "sensor3": 73, "sensor2": 75, "sensor5": 73, "id": 4}, {"sensor4": 73, "sensor1": 76, "sensor3": 73, "sensor2": 75, "sensor5": 73, "id": 5}]} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Answer (score 1):

edit your string to this format

```
{content:[{
              first:1,
              second:76,
              third:75
          },
          {
              first:2,
              second:76,
              third:75
          },
          {
              first:3,
              second:206,
              third:75
          },
          {
              first:4,
              second:6,
              third:175
          },
          {
              first:5,
              second:176,
              third:75
          }]
}
```

then use JSONObject and JSONArray to convert string

```
JSONArray array = new JSONObject(string).getJSONArray("content");
for(int i=0;i<array.size();i++){
    JSONObject obj = array.get(i);
    Log.i(TAG,"obj.getInt = "+obj.getInt("first"));
    Log.i(TAG,"obj.getInt = "+obj.getInt("second"));
    Log.i(TAG,"obj.getInt = "+obj.getInt("third"));
}
```